# SwiftUI macOS place toolbar item to the rightmost position when dispaying a search bar

Tags: macos, swiftui, nstoolbar

Since macOS 13, the primaryAction no longer displays next on left to the search bar

[image]

```
    MainView()
    .toolbar {
        ToolbarItem {
            Spacer()
        }
        ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .status) {
            Text("Status")
        }
        ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .principal) {
            Text("Principal")
        }
        ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .primaryAction) {
            Text("Primary")
        }
        ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .keyboard) {
            Text("Keyboard")
        }
        ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .secondaryAction) {
            Text("Secondary")
        }
        ToolbarItem {
            Text("Noplacement")
        }
    }
    .searchable(text: .constant(""))
```

how to position a toolbar item the topmost right next to search?

Note: without the search bar, they are put correctly to rightmost position

Comment: Hello Peter, I have the same issue there. I can't put a toolbar item just at left of the searchBar (or right). The last item is at 200 pixels of the searchBar...

Comment: didn't found a solution yet too... you can upvote this question, so it gets more publicity and maybe a resolve

Comment: I sent a radar to Apple. It looks like a macOS swiftUI bug.

Comment: i belive this is intention

Answer (score 1):

On macOS Sonoma, adding a `ToolbarItem` with just a `Spacer` inside creates the "Flexible Space" item which it's normally used in macOS toolbars to align elements.

With this, there's no need to provide a value for `placement`, as you will be able to place elements in any position.

```swift
ToolbarItem(
  id: "flexible-space-id" // Provide a ID to allow for toolbar customization
) {
  Spacer()
}
```

[image: Customizable toolbar with flexible space items]

Answer (score -1):

You simply need to add a Spacer()

```
   .toolbar {     
     ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .primaryAction) {
                            Spacer()
                            Text("Primary")
                        }
   }
   .searchable(text: .constant(""))
```

[Here's what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxfWp.png)

Comment: this doesn't work

Comment: @PeterLapisu you must be doing something wrong since I use this literally in all my apps. What exactly "doesn't work"?

Comment: there still is flexible space after... may not be noticeable when the window has small width, but as the window grows, the gap between search and the item gets larger